# how should i use react lazy-loading

Tags: reactjs, axios, flicker

I'm building a simple Gallery App in react, which searches the flickr API for images base on user input.

When the user loads many images, the browser can become slow and sometimes stuck altogether, how can I improve browser performance, and improve the UI?
I'm trying to achieve this with lazy-loading, but I'm struggling to implement it

```
Gallary render

render() {
    return (
      <div className="gallery-root"  
           id = "gallery-id"
           ref = "iScroll"
           >
        {this.state.images.map(dto => {
          return <Image 
                  key={'image-' + dto.id} 
                  dto={dto}
                  galleryWidth={this.state.galleryWidth}
                  callBack = {this.cloneHandler.bind(this)}
                  displayImage = {this.renderImage.bind(this)}
                  />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

```
Image Render

render() { 

    return ( 
      <div  
        className="image-root"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${this.urlFromDto(this.props.dto)})`,
          width: this.state.size + 'px',
          height: this.state.size + 'px',
          filter: this.state.filter
        }}
        > 
        <div>
          <FontAwesome 
                      className="image-icon" 
                      name="clone" 
                      title="clone"
                      onClick = {this.ClickCloneHandler.bind(this) } />
          <FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="filter" title="filter"
                       onClick = {this.ClickFilterHandler}/>
          <FontAwesome className="image-icon" name="expand" title="expand"
                        onClick = {this.ClickExpandHandler.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
      </div> 
    );
  }
```

i want to lazy-load the images and improve browser performance.

Maybe use react lifecycles functions in order to get the best performance?

What is the best practice for this case?

Comment: Have you considered lazy loading your images ?

Comment: I did, not sure how to implement lazy-loading